# Asymptotic behavior of counting functions

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose we have $G$ primes (some or all of them may be the same). Let $\pi_G(x)$ -  function, which counts all the natural numbers less then $x$, factorized by using   no more than G any primes. Then, for $G = 1$, it will be the prime  counting function, $G = 2$ - a function counting primes and two-part numbers less then $x$ and so on. Obviously, this function for $x < 2^{G+1}$ counts all consecutive natural numbers and then will be  deviation because not all natural numbers can be fuctorized with G or less primes.  I would like to know the asymptotic behavior $\pi_G(x)$ for large $x$

EDIT: And what will be the result if we have first G primes i.e. function, which counts all the natural numbers less then $x$, factorized by using  *only first* $G$ primes $p_1=2, p_2=3, ..., p_G$ *in any powers*? Apparently, defined in this way, the function $ \pi_G(x)$ must tends to $x$ when $G$ tends to  infinity, but the question is how fast it tends (the error term).

Comment: This [MO thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35927/asymptotic-density-of-k-almost-primes) may help too,

Answer (score 2):

For fixed $G$, this is a classical result of Landau—see the bottom of [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_prime) for the asymptotic formula.